# Stop the Chain in pipe operator

Tags: elixir

I have tre functions like this

```
check_file(url) |>test |> foo
```

check_file return

```
{:ok,_} or {:error,_}
```

I have Two function for pattern matching

```
  def test({:ok,_}) do
     IO.puts "ok";
  end

  def test({:error,_}) do
     IO.puts "KO, debug and stop!";
  end
```

If I got :error I don't want to call my last function (foo) but I'd like to show an error in Debug

Can I do This ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [with](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/docs-tests-and-with.html#with) statement in elixir like this

```
with {:ok, file} <- check_file(url) do
    file |> foo |> foo
else 
  IO.puts "KO, debug and stop!"
end
```

This is especially useful if `test` returns an 
`{:ok, something}`  tuple too. Then you can expand the `with`

If you only have the possibility for an error at the beginning in your `check_file(url)` method you can do an simple solution like this:

```
def test({:ok,file}) do
   IO.puts "ok";
   do_your_stuff_with_the_file()t |> foo
end

def test({:error,_}) do
     IO.puts "KO, debug and stop!";
  end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, in this way I have to add this condition to each function `check_file(url) |>test |> foo |> bar |>buz' right? thanks

Comment: it depends what the function are returning. if they return a ```{:ok, something}˚˚˚ or ˚˚˚{:error, some_error}``` you should use the ```with``` since you can handle more than one of those tuples and have the error handling in one place for all of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple case instead:

```
case check_file(url) do
  {:ok, file} ->
    IO.puts "ok"
    foo(file)
  {:error, _} ->
    IO.puts "KO, debug and stop!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to add support to `{:error, _}` pattern to function `foo`:

```
  def foo({:ok,_}) do
     IO.puts "do the stuff";
  end
  def foo({:error,_}), do: {:error, []}
```

but in this kind of solution you need to return `{:error}`  from `test`.

Answer (score 0):

What is not mentioned in other answers, is that you can raise some specific error in `test` function and then catch it in whatever code wraps in your pipe. Only this way you can truly stop any arbitrary long pipe.

But I wouldn't do it. I'd rather code my program in the way I don't need to stop a pipe by raising an error.